# Configurable Product Sold Out - Showing in stock / Add to Cart and Drop Down Blank

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, addtocart

We have set a configurable product and it has sizes below.

When all sizes are sold out the add to cart is still present and the drop down for size is visible with no item i.e small

The product also shows "in stock" which is wrong